# Moving DataGridViewRow by 1cm in 1 hour

Tags: winforms, datagridview, scroll

For Winform DataGridView, what I want to do is move the rows up/down by 1 cm in 1 hour. I googled about it but could not find anything which can give me a clue. Just to be more specific, let's say I have a Form open on my  machine with DataGridView filled with data. And if I will look at the DataGridView after 1 hour it should be moved by 1cm up/down. The movement should be in such  a way that user won't even realize and there won't be any problem while clicking/selecting cells/rows.

Can someone please point me where to start and how can I implement this?

**Note: The Grid will stay as it is. Just the rows will go up/down by 1 cm in 1 hour.**
Thanks,
MChicago

Answer (score 0):

This code will auto-scroll the DataGridView using a timer: to move 1com in one hour, you will have to find the right value for interval by experimentation..

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly Timer tmr = new Timer();
        private int start;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tmr.Interval = 100;
            tmr.Tick += scrollGrid;
            tmr.Enabled = true;

            List<DisplayItem> list = new List<DisplayItem>
                {
                    new DisplayItem("Apple"),
                    new DisplayItem("Orange"),
                    new DisplayItem("Banana"),
                    new DisplayItem("Grape")
                };
            // Make a long enough list to see the scrolling
            dgv.DataSource = list.Concat(list).Concat(list).ToList();
        }    

        private void scrollGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyInfo verticalOffset = dgv.GetType()
               .GetProperty("VerticalOffset", BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                              BindingFlags.Instance);


            start += 1;
            verticalOffset.SetValue(this.dgv, start, null);
        }

        private class DisplayItem
        {
            public DisplayItem(string s)
            {
                this.Value = s;
            }

            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart for the sample. I tried the code and moves entire row after some time. I need to have a smooth scrolling. So, once the timer is fired it should move the row let's for example only 1/20 of the row.